# How to combine dates using lead function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a `generate_series` function to extract dates between a `start_date` and `end_date` and I'm trying to combine dates using `daterange`. I wrote this query:

```
     with a as(
select d.day::date as day from (select * from generate_series('2018-08-22'::timestamp, '2019-07-12'::timestamp, 
concat(greatest(date_part('days','2019-07-12'::timestamp - '2018-08-22'::timestamp)/8,1), ' day')::interval)) as d(day))
select daterange(day,(lead(day) over (order by day) - interval '1 day')::date,'[]')
FROM a
```

I got these results:

```
"[2018-08-22,2018-10-01)"
"[2018-10-01,2018-11-11)"
"[2018-11-11,2018-12-21)"
"[2018-12-21,2019-01-31)"
"[2019-01-31,2019-03-12)"
"[2019-03-12,2019-04-22)"
"[2019-04-22,2019-06-01)"
"[2019-06-01,2019-07-12)"
"[2019-07-12,)"
```

I don't want to display the last row `"[2019-07-12,)"`. How can I manage my query to not display the last row which contains `Infinity` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the `lead()` into the CTE and use logic based on that:

```
with dr as (
      select gs.day::date as day, lead(gs.day) over (order by day) as next_day
      from generate_series('2018-08-22'::timestamp, '2019-07-12'::timestamp, 
                           concat(greatest(date_part('days','2019-07-12'::timestamp - '2018-08-22'::timestamp)/8,1), ' day')::interval
                          ) gs(day)
     )
select daterange(day, (next_day - interval '1 day')::date)
from dr
where next_day is not null
```